# Which browsers will automatically load and view a PDF from an anchor link

Tags: pdf

I have a client who is asking about having PDFs viewable in the browser. Chrome will load the PDF as will Safari, however an older version of Firefox (12) I have installed will download the file. Any way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code,

```
<object data="mypdf.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

<p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="mypdf.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>

</object>
```